# Programmatically set Sitecore.Context

Tags: presentation, admin-pages

I'm trying to build a custom admin utility page which will add renderings to a page.
The action happens in an Ajax call and so the Sitecore.Context is unavailable.
I do have the `pageItem` though.

```
LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(pageItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
var contextDb = Sitecore.Context.Database;
DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());
```

In the above code, `contextDb` is null & `deviceDefition` throws an error because `Sitecore.Context.Device` is null.

Is there a way to programmatically set the `Sitecore.Context` or get it from the `pageItem`.

Using Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Instead of using `Sitecore.Context.Database` just use `pageItem.Database`. There is no way of getting the device from the request of admin page. Easiest way is to pass `deviceId` to your ajax request

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have tried getting `Sitecore.Context.Device.ID` in the `Page_Load` event of the aspx custom-admin-page. It is null. Should this page inherit from any other class. I have created many admin pages before that do item manipulations like create/update etc. But this is the first one that needs `Sitecore.Context`. Please suggest.

Comment: How can Sitecore possibly know which device you need? It's not there on admin page. But I suppose you always want default device on your admin page. In that case, you can just hardcode the value, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `pageItem` which is an instance of `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` class, you can wrap your code into a `DatabaseSwitcher` and `DeviceSwitcher`

```
        using (new DatabaseSwitcher(pageItem.Database))
        {
            using (new DeviceSwitcher(pageItem.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name.Equals("default",System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))))
            {
                // Add your code block here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve device item, you can use this:

```
var deviceItem = Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem.ResolveDevice(pageItem.Database);
```

Then you can use one of the approaches below:

1. `Sitecore.Context.Device = deviceItem; // doesn't validate deviceItem`
2. `Sitecore.Context.Data.Device = deviceItem; // validates deviceItem`
3. `using(new DeviceSwitcher(deviceItem)) { /*your code here*/ }`

You also can use the switchers below (if needed) to switch Context.Database and Context.Item if they are null:

1. `using (new DatabaseSwitcher(pageItem.Database)) {}`
2. `using (new ContextItemSwitcher(pageItem)) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore can do all this for you as well without the need to write any custom code when you pass the Guid of the item in `sc_itemid` query string in your Ajax call. I just tested and this will get `Sitecore.Context.Device` populated with default device.

Note that you might need more querystrings if you are after additional info. For example Sitecore cannot determine the context site unless you also specify `sc_site`